# Gitlab: using an artifact created in job1 inside a container that's being built in job2

Tags: docker, gitlab, yaml

I have successfully created an artifact and have proven to myself that it's available to the next job / the job where I need it.  But I actually need to use it inside a container that i'm building.
but I don't know how to do this.
Here's what I have so far:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

job_that_creates:
  image: node:10.19
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - make
    - make source-package
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    when:
    paths:
      - my.tar.bz2
    expire_in: 2 days

job_that_consumes:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls -lah
```

The output from the "ls" command shows me the tar file.
But ultimately, I need to do something like this in the job_that_consumes:

```
job_that_consumes:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls -lah
  image: custom_image
    - somehow extract the zip to a specific location.
```

I've been trying to google but so far, I haven't picked the right key words.  Presently looking at how to copy into a container.

**EDIT 1**

For now, what I'm testing is copying the tar to the volume on the host for the runner, and then from there copying to the container.
But the reason I don't like this is I feel like I'm marrying the container to the host … and I'd have to be sure that I create runners on all my hosts the exact same way.
Is there a better way?

Comment: what is `custom_image` ? The image you want to build ?

Comment: So just to clarify: You have a artifact in job1 and you need it in the deployed container of job2, not within the script of job2 itself?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper correct

Comment: @MichéeLengronne yes.  Sorry I will upate my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @dot Then my answer should help you :)

Comment: You can also build your image in you gitlab-ci. You have to add a DinD service or mount the docker socket in your runner (DinD makes the container less married to the host ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand your question correctly, you want to have the artefact within the docker container you are deploy in step2?!

That is not easy possible because the job is running in a so called gitlab-runner. The runner is not persistent, so when the runner ends, all data is lost. That is why we have artefacts.

Now the good thing:
Artefacts are available from outside of gitlab for 4 weeks default (you can even have artefacts there longer or shorter), mean you can reach it and download it with every application you like (e.g. curl).

Here is the gitlab documentation to this feature:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts

Copying that tar, like you say within your edit, is not even a bad thing by design.
I dont see why that should be a worse solution then downloading it by curl later, its just a more narrow solution because it only works WHILE your runner is alive, while the downloading method works for weeks afterwards.